# WebJob method NotSupportedException Saving Image to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-webjobs

I am trying to save a thumbnail from within a WebJob BlobTrigger and I am getting the following Exception:

An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Specified method is not supported.

I have broken the code down to its simplest elements and still get the exception on bitmap.Save

```
    public static void CreateThumbnailsForNewlyUploadedPNGs([BlobTrigger("files/{name}.{ext}")] Stream input, [Blob("files/{name}~25.png", FileAccess.Write)] Stream output25, string name, string ext)
    {
        using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(input))
        {
            bitmap.Save(output25, ImageFormat.Png);
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions what might be going wrong?

Comment: I should mention I based this code on Scott Hanselman's blog post:  [http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingWindowsAzureWebJobs.aspx](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingWindowsAzureWebJobs.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with webjobs but I looked at the article you mentioned and came up with something. I basically kept it as close to Scotts article as I could. My attribute for the second parameter is BlobOutput instead of Blob.

```
public static void CreateThumbnailsForNewlyUploadedPNGs(
    [BlobTrigger("files/{name}.{ext}")] Stream input,
    [BlobOutput("files/{name}~25.png")] Stream output,
    string name,
    string ext)
{
    using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(input))
    {
        bitmap.Save(output, ImageFormat.Png);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Michael however in the new SDK BlobOutput has been changed to Blob.
_Microsoft has also made few modifications by which a triggered QueueInput has been renamed as QueueTrigger and QueueOutput has become Queue. In the same way, a Triggered BlobInput has been renamed to BlobTrigger but a BlobInput or BlobOutput is Blob._

[http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/06/ms-azure-webjobs-sdk-3-beta]